# FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher only returning the company app hub

Tags: windows-phone-8, app-hub

I'm developing a Company App Hub and after successfully installing an app I'm not able to launch it as when I retrieve the apps already installed for current publisher I only get the one actually running the query (i.e. the Company App Hub).

I've already checked that both the Company App Hub and the Installed App share the same Publisher ID (at least on the WMAppManifest.xml).

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is related to the Publisher ID.

The correct Publisher ID is the one created with your Symantec ID put to hex and then converted to GUID adding 0000 0000 000000000000 (more or less, adjust trailing zeros)